# How to smooth interior polygons of one shapefile

Tags: simplify, generalization, smoothing

I have a shapefile that includes the boundary of a field plus many interior polygons that represent levels of NDVI - we'll say High, Medium, and Low. The larger areas have jagged, irregular edges. There are also many many small (tiny) polygons. I'd like to eliminate the small ones and smooth the larger ones.

I've tried v.generalize.smooth and v.generalize.simply as well as the Smooth Geometry tool but nothing changes in the shapefile no matter what I do. I THINK it's only trying to act on the boundary of the shapefile which actually consists of very straight lines (maybe 30 vertices total).

[image]

Comment: Are you working in QGIS or GRASS GIS?

Comment: Make sure to have single geometries and not multi.